# Are there any risks to using triggers for DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS vs listing specific event types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, ddl

I have a DDL trigger that logs database schema changes to a table for auditing purposes. I noticed that some changes I made were missed (like creating a type - `CREATE_TYPE`) and need to update it.

My understanding is that DDL events are always triggered by a human. Is that true? Is there any chance of a trigger like this causing queries to fail?

This trigger is defined like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [name_of_trigger]
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE, CREATE_INDEX, ALTER_INDEX, DROP_INDEX, ...
```

Are there any risks to just using the catch-all `DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS` like this?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [name_of_trigger]
ON DATABASE
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
```

or is it safer or better practice to specify all the types I know I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using such a trigger (for `DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS`) and I am specifically excepting the event type `UPDATE_STATISTICS`. You may want to also avoid `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` and `ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE`.